# How to put Wordpress files in the Laravel root directory so that a URL shows like, 'www.domain.com/url' given in laravel and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5

We have an existing site on WordPress and our member pages are hardcoded in Laravel. We want to add the whole WordPress site (not just blogs, but also pages, plugin files, media, and more) in our Laravel root directory.

When we put them in a folder named wpfiles, the url for all WordPress pages changed from

> www.domain.com/xyz

to

> www.domain.com/wpfiles/xyz

Is there a way we can add WordPress files in the Laravel root directory without having the folder name in the URL?

Comment: Place your WordPress directory code inside the `public` directory in laravel code.

Comment: Do keep in mind that Laravel has its own .htaccess file in the public directory. Overwriting that might end up breaking your Laravel application, so test things first on a local/staging server.